# Jenkins always pull docker image from a declarative pipeline agent definition

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a working Jenkins pipeline defined with `agent {any}`.

But I want to try running the tests on a docker image. According to documentation I can do that the following way:

```
pipeline {
     agent {
         docker { image 'centos/python-27-centos7:latest' }
     }
     stages {
        ...
     }
}
```

The problem is that my instance of Jenkins is offline and with this configuration it will try to `docker pull` the image when running the project.

However I have the centos/python-27 image loaded in the docker (visible with `docker images` and it can be run with `docker run -i -t centos/python-27-centos7 /bin/bash`

Is there any way I can configure the agent in Jenkins so it doesn't try to `pull` the image from Docker Hub?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Docker agent has an `alwaysPull` flag you can set to `false` or `true`:

```
agent {
  docker {
    alwaysPull false
    image 'foo/bar'
  }
}
```

---

Jenkins has a Pipeline Syntax Generator that can help in these cases. In the Job menu on the left side, there is an icon for "Pipeline Syntax".

[image]

There you can see some settings to help you generate your pipeline directives.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a dockerfile agent.  If everything you need to build the image is local, then you won't have to be online.

```
pipeline {
 agent {
   dockerfile {
     filename "someOtherDockerfile"
     label "docker-nodes"
     args "-v /tmp:/tmp"
   }
 }
 stages {
    ...
 }
```

Your other option is possibly setting up a private docker registry.
https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

Answer (score 0):

You should us **siblings** instead of **nested** container images. i.e. Try to mount the volume of docker daemon sockets to the Jenkins container via `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`. This way, you will get access to the images available on your host system.

Comment: you can mount the docker socket and still use
agent {
         docker { 
               image 'centos/python-27-centos7:latest' 
               args "-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
         }
     }